# Code works in code tester but not in adressbar

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

If i input my code here:
http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/
It works as intended, but if i input it in my adressbar with "javascript:" infront the alert box just shows the original string.
What is going wrong?

```
var string = "Sunshine & Whiskey";
var stringFeedback;
var i = 0;

string = string.replace("&","%26");

do {
    stringFeedback = string.search(/[ ]/);
    string = string.replace(/[ ]/,"%20");
    i += 1;
} while (i < 5);

alert(string);
```

Edit:
If i input in my Chromium console it works fine, but if i make a bookmark with the same code it doesn't.
Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: It's a 12 line code block. How exactly do you paste it in the browser location bar, which can only hold one line?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Easy. The browser just replaces newlines with spaces. At least Chrome does.

Comment: BTW, your code doesn't work for me, not even in the site you link. It throws an *Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined* error message because you never declare `i` before increment it.

Comment: @Scimonster - Owesome! That's what I call progress!

Comment: ... uhm... to replace special character you can use `encodeURIComponent("Sunshine & Whiskey")` that return: "Sunshine%20%26%20Whiskey". (is a suggestion, sorry for OT)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I don't know how it happened, but i pasted an old snippet.

Comment: @Frogmouth Yeah, i googled for something like that but couldn't find one.
Thanks!

Comment: :) glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Try initialising `i` before the loop:

```
var i = 0;
do {
    stringFeedback = string.search(/[ ]/);
    string = string.replace(/[ ]/,"%20");
    i += 1;
} while (i < 5);
```

*Whatever, I recommend you use your browser console to test these code snippets.*

Comment: Neat didn't think about the console.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
encodeURIComponent("Sunshine & Whiskey");
```

That returns

```
Sunshine%20%26%20Whiskey
```

without any loop, it's a native method of javascript that is supported by all Browser.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)